# Can rotational motion can be reduced to translational motion?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, popular-science, phase-space

Susskind says that all physics (dynamics of the world) can be described in terms of particle positions and their first order derivatives. Does such translational motion gives rise to rotation?

Comment: Reference? Video?

Comment: @Anixx [rotation is a rigid body movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation#Mathematics) which, unlike [a translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_(geometry)), keeps a point fixed point.

Comment: I changed transnational to translational. I truly doubt that valentin was asking about people crossing national boundaries. I suspect that valentin instead encountered a DYAC (blank you, auto-correct!) moment where some mistyped word was auto-magically auto-corrected incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the full context of what he says, he is most likely saying this in the context of classical physics, and it is most likely that he is saying that in this physics, particle dynamics are described by second order differential equations. Thus, if we know the positions and velocities of all the particles at any one time, these data fully define the future motions of all the particles.

Where rotation fits in is in situations like the following. In a rigid body (or approximation thereto) or any other system where there is circular motion / nonzero angular momentum (*e.g.* a system of planets) there are forces between the particles making up the body and these are defined by known physics. So the system of differential equations describing the rotating body / planetary system would be a *coupled* system, and the forces between the particles would define the coupling terms. So the system's history of behaviour is still wholly defined by initial positions and velocities but we do not needfully have translational motion, and it is the forces between the particles that beget the deviation from translational motion.